# How to perform form validation in Angular 2

Tags: validation, angular

I'm currently on Angular 2's `2.0.0-rc.1` version and I'm trying to create some basic form validation but I haven't moved forwards with this in days because I can't get past this error:

```
No provider for ControlContainer
```

I checked [this open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6374) on Github but little info is given why this is happening or how to solve it. Seems like this has been around since the first beta version.

I've tried to import and inject most things that's form related (`FORM_PROVIDERS`, `FORM_DIRECTIVES` you name it), but my most recent attempt is this:

```
import {NgForm, ControlContainer} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-input',
  templateUrl: 'alonglongtemplateurl.html',
  styleUrls: ['alonglongstyleurl.css'],
  directives: [
    NgForm
  ],
  providers: [
    ControlContainer
  ]
})
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <input ngControl="name">
</div>
```

Then I use it like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <form-input></form-input>
</form>
```

Despite me injecting what it asks for I still get the same error.

What is the correct way of using validation for form elements in Angular 2 since the latest release?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've read that a billion times but their example doesn't work.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ihYc9y7dQA0

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Look at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to have a form element around your input to use `ngControl`:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input ngControl="name">
  </form>
</div>
```

Directives for form are part of the platform ones so you don't need to include them explicitly. Same for providers.

Comment: I do, but outside of the component.

Comment: I think that's the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could leverage ng-include. See this article (section "Form component for fields"): http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/. This way your input will be part of the form...

Comment: Great! Thanks! To make your form-input part of the high-level form you need to make the corresponding component implements a value accessor. This way you will be able to use `ngControl` directly on it. Something like that: `<form-input ngForm="name"></form-input>`. The problem in your case is that you use the template-driven approach to define validation. So you can't link the ngControl in your sub component with the outter form. That said I think that it's possible if you use the `FormBuilder` class but it's the other approch to define validation ;-)

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or something which shows a functioning validation? Because I can't even get it to work without a component...

Comment: Perhaps this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568126/custom-checkbox-input-component-styled-with-switchery/36570658 and this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/z1gAC5U0pgMSq0wicGHC?p=preview could help you ;-)

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of work to get a simple component working with an outside form... How can they not have thought of making this simpler..

Comment: If you use FormBuilder and ngFormControl, you can define the control for your component in the parent component and provide it as input the child component. Something like that: `<form-input [control]="myForm.controls.name"></form-input>`. And have the corresponding input in the child component: `@Input() control:Control;`

Comment: I have no control over what's outside of the component, as I'm writing it to be generic so that it can be used anywhere. It shouldn't even have to be used in a form. Is validation "the angular 2 way" still possible if the input isn't in a form?

Comment: Yes but you need to instantiate by hand your control and link it to the input with the `ngFormControl` directive. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/yZL1wRw7GYhUkkhnL9S0?p=info.

Comment: I tried adding `[ngFormControl]="model"` (have a model `@Input()`) and then setting it in the constructor like `this.model = new Control()` but it throws this error: `Cannot find control ""` what does that even mean? I'm creating a new Control for the love of....

Comment: I just realised that the validation classes gets added with or without the form controls set on the input, which solves the issue completely since all I really need here is visual presentation of errors. What does ngControl offer beyond validation classes being added to the element?