# Angular 2 Add control to parent component's form

Tags: angular

I have an autocomplete complete with template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model"> //todo add control
```

It is implemented as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="location">Location</label>
  <auto-complete [(model)]="model.location"></auto-complete>
</div>
```

Alongside it, I have other fields which follow this format: (Notice validation directives)

```
<div class="form-group" [fieldValidity]="biography">
  <label for="currentPassword">Biography</label>
  <textarea
    [(ngModel)]="model.biography" ngControl="biography" #biography="ngForm" maxlength="300"
    class="form-control" placeholder="About me..." rows="4"></textarea>
    <p class="xui-meta-info">
      We suggest a short bio. If it's 300 characters or less it'll look great on your profile.
    </p>
  <field-validation-messages [field]="biography"></field-validation-messages>
</div>
```

As you can see, my validation directives rely on the input having an associated control on the form. How can I ensure my input in auto complete has an associated control in the parent form? (I've tried programmatically creating a new Control() and then calling form.addControl() but that only accepts an NgControl

Comment: What does "create a control on the input" mean?

Comment: On my other inputs (in the parent component) I am using "ngControl="fullName" etc. I need to do similar for this, I need a control for the input to exist on the parent form so that my validation (in the parent component) can use form.controls['location'].errors for example.

Comment: Please provide more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Ideally a Plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `auto-complete` component compliant with control by implementing a custom value accessor.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'auto-complete',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)>
  `,
  (...)
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.model = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

This way you can directly add control your auto complete component this way:

```
<auto-complete
  [(model)]="model.location"
  [ngFormControl]="someCtrl">
  <!-- or #autoComplete="ngForm" ngControl="autoComplete" -->
</auto-complete>
```

For more details, see this article (section "NgModel-compatible component"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

This question could also help you:

- [Custom checkbox input component styled with Switchery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568126/custom-checkbox-input-component-styled-with-switchery/36570658#36570658)

Comment: Thanks Thierry! I'm getting " No value accessor for 'location'". Is there an easy fix for that? Or do I need to write a custom value accessor?

Comment: If I implement it as [ngFormControl]="location". I get an error "Cannot find control ''''. I'm guessing that's because I didn't create a new Control() on my parent? The reason I didn't do that is because I need the control added to the form for validation purposes and I noticed that form.addControl() only accepts ngControl, not control, so I couldn't add it in.

Then If I implement it as "#location="ngForm" ngControl="location", I get the error: "No value accessor for 'location". location doesn't exist anywhere, I assumed it would create a control for me.

Comment: Yes, I think you use it the right way with `#location="ngForm" ngControl="location` but the element you apply on must support control. If it's your autocomplete component, it needs to implement a custom value accessor as described in my answer...