# Mask directive in Angular 2 not working on load view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I made some mask directives in Angular 2, one of them is for zip code. It mostly works but when loading the data in HTML, it only works when the focus is on the input that has the directive. I've tried putting various events in host, but none worked. I tried to use change, input, but none worked.

**HTML:**

*input has the directive (directive name: cep)*

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group fg-line">
            <label for="cep">CEP</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cep" placeholder="CEP" required [(ngModel)]="empresa.Cep" borda-animada
                cep maxlength="9" ngControl="cep" #cep="ngForm">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Directive:**

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/common';
import {Mascaras} from '../core/mascaras'

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][cep]',
    providers: [NgModel],
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'onInputChange($event)',
        '(input)': 'onInputChange($event)'
    }
})
export class CepDirective {
    modelValue: string;
    viewValue: string;

constructor(public model: NgModel) {}

onInputChange(event) {
  console.log('teste ngmodelchange');

  //event é o evento html que é disparado no evento blur
  //por isso precisa pegar o target.value.
  var newValue = Mascaras.cep(event.target.value);
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(newValue);       
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess using a custom `ControlValueAccessor` would be the right approach.

Comment: Do you have some exemple?

Comment: There are lots of answers here to similar questions mostly from Thierry. Just search `[angular2] ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384373/angular-2-add-control-to-parent-components-form/37384802#37384802

Answer (score 0):

If you provide `NgModel` in the directive, it gets a new instance injected instead of the existing one.

This line needs to be removed:

```
providers: [NgModel],
```

[Input mask fields in Angular2 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms) shows a full example.