# Angular Add Control to form from child component

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 2, I have a child component that includes an input. I want to add this input (control) to the parent components form (NgForm).

I am currently using Template Driven Forms for simplicity.

I saw this answer, but think it is likely outdated?: [Angular 2 Add control to parent component's form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384373/angular-2-add-control-to-parent-components-form)

Child Component Template:
formInputName is an input binding so that I can reuse this component, and add the 'name' property dynamically.

```
<input class="text-input" [name]="formInputName" [id]="formInputName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
            (change)="onChange(searchValue)"
            (blur)="onBlur()"
            (focus)="onFocus()"
            [required]="isRequired">
```

On the parent component I have an instance of the form:

```
    @ViewChild('testForm') testForm: NgForm;
```

How can I add the child components control to this instance of [NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)? I'm not sure how to do it with [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#addControl). Not sure what I need to add in the template, or how to do it programmatically in the controller.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rDluyJduyHF7vclK9wRE?p=preview

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/rDluyJduyHF7vclK9wRE?p=preview

Comment: you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for `test-component` component. See [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83). You can edit your question to add some clarifications after you've read the article

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you try this, and see if it is working,

> Child component

```
@Output() childControl = new EventEmitter<NgModel>(); // import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
@ViewChild('myControl') myControl: NgModel;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.childControl.emit(myControl); // emitting the control to the parent to be picked up there and added to the main form
}
```

> Child template

```
<input #myControl="ngModel" class="text-input" [name]="formInputName" [id]="formInputName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
            (change)="onChange(searchValue)"
            (blur)="onBlur()"
            (focus)="onFocus()"
            [required]="isRequired">
```

> Parent template

```
<child-component (childControl)="childControlReady($event)"></child-component>
```

> Parent component

```
childControlReady(control: NgModel) {
 this.testform.addControl(control);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The #myControl giving me the reference to ngModel was the key.

Comment: What should the `EventEmitter` return when using ReactiveForms (I'm not using ngModel)? I have tried this solution but the newly added control won't update its value after it's added to the formgroup.