# Angular2: Checkbox with radio button functionality

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Can I get a guidance in implementing radio button functionality in checkbox using angular2 ?
I tried with same name and ngModel, but not working

Here is my component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="conformityForm">     
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Evaluation</th>
           <th>Yes</th>
           <th>No</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Do the staff have adequate qualifications for the tasks?</td>
          <td>
             <input type="checkbox" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsYes">
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type="checkbox" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsNo">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 </form>
```

component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

  export class Test implements OnInit {
   conformityForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)      
      this.conformityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'IsInConvenienceYes': [''],
        'IsInConvenienceNo': ['']
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why implement checkbox when you want radio functionality? Seems counter intuitive

Comment: @AnnMary are you trying to do something like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568126/custom-checkbox-input-component-styled-with-switchery

Comment: @Huangism I need checkbox ui, but functionality seems to work like radio button.

Comment: @visery, Not like that.I just want two checkboxes, which act like radio button., i.e, only one checkbox to be checked at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I wasn't really thinking this true, so you did not want to disable the field when other checkbox is checked. But here is the solution for the radio button behavior. We are using the same variables `yes` and `no`, like below. Here we just patch the values with `false` and `true` that will uncheck the other if the other is checked. So change your template to this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="yes.patchValue(true) ? yes.patchValue(true) : no.patchValue(false)" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsYes">
<input type="checkbox" (change)="no.patchValue(true) ? no.patchValue(false) : yes.patchValue(false)" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsNo">
```

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKzz9LfhyTfqbonnNCZ2?p=preview)**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As a first comment I can say that the usual `[disabled]` doesn't work with reactive forms, so we need to do it in another way.

I like to shorten the form controls for better readability, here I have used variables `yes` and `no`, you maybe want to do some more suitable names? Anyway, they are defined in the TS like so:

```html
this.yes = this.conformityForm.get('IsAdequatequalificationsYes');
this.no = this.conformityForm.get('IsAdequatequalificationsNo');
```

Then we add a change event to the form, where we check if the current checkbox is checked, if so, we disable the other one, and the other way around using the ternary operator. So do the following for the `yes`:

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="yes.value ? no.disable() : no.enable()" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsYes">
```

and for the `no` we just change it to the opposite.

That should do it! :)

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRyk4Oc1iEJKmdflyvwO?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks AJT_82, I am getting an Error as " Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.
  Property 'registerOnChange' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'."

Comment: Where is this error thrown? Could you perhaps fork the plunker I provided and try to reproduce the issue? Can't pinpoint based on the error message as of where this error could reside.

Comment: error is thrown in:this.yes = this.conformityForm.get('IsAdequatequalificationsYes');
this.no = this.conformityForm.get('IsAdequatequalificationsNo');

Comment: Well the plunker is working, have you checked and rechecked that it matches your code? :)

Comment: I think its due to Form control you declared.I have changed it to 'yes: any;
    no: any;' instead of ' yes: FormControl;
  no: FormControl;'

Comment: Have you imported `FormControl`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146507/discussion-between-annmary-and-ajt-82).

Comment: @timbru31, well, at the end I do not know what was the issue really, when I provided the plunker in my edited answer, we got it working, but never found out really what was not working before that. Are you facing that issue? If so, could you provide a plunker and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use this option:

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="yes.patchValue(true); no.patchValue(false);" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsYes">
<input type="checkbox" (change)="yes.patchValue(false); no.patchValue(true);" formControlName="IsAdequatequalificationsNo">
```